# ruamel.yaml custom CommentedMapping for custom tags

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I've got a YAML file with custom tags that looks like this:

```
flow123d_version: 3.1.0
problem: !modulek.Coupling_Sequential
  description: Simple dual porosity test - steady flow, simple transport
  mesh:
    mesh_file: ../00_mesh/square_1x1_40el.msh
  flow_equation: !Flow_Darcy_MH
    nonlinear_solver:
      linear_solver: !Petsc
        a_tol: 1.0e-07
```

and so far my code can load it and dump it back. My problem is that I would like to be able to check on every custom `!` and check with other files if it is correct. Let's look at second line of my file. You can see there is my first custom tag and it consist of module.class_name and i need to check on both of them. I want to parse out 'modulek' as a module and 'Coupling_Sequential' as class_name. My code looks like this.

```
import types
import re

import ruamel.yaml as ruml
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap, CommentedSeq

CommentsTag = ruml.comments.Tag


class CommentedScalar:
    """
    Class to store all scalars with their tags
    """
    original_constructors = {}

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, dumper, data):
        representer = dumper.yaml_representers[type(data.value).__mro__[0]]
        node = representer(dumper, data.value)
        if data.tag.value is None:
            tag = node.tag
        elif data.tag.value.startswith(u'tag:yaml.org,2002'):
            tag = node.tag
        else:
            tag = data.tag.value
        # print("val: ", data.value, "repr: ", node.value, "tag: ", tag)
        return dumper.represent_scalar(tag, node.value)

    def __init__(self, tag, value):
        complete_tag = tag.split('.')
        self.tag.value = tag
        self.value = value
        # self.module.value = complete_tag
        self.module = '.'.join(complete_tag[:len(complete_tag) - 1])
        self.class_name = complete_tag[-1]

    @property
    def tag(self):
        # type: () -> Any
        if not hasattr(self, CommentsTag.attrib):
            setattr(self, CommentsTag.attrib, CommentsTag())
        return getattr(self, CommentsTag.attrib)

def construct_any_tag(self, tag_suffix, node):
    if tag_suffix is None:
        orig_tag = None
    else:
        orig_tag = "!" + tag_suffix
    if isinstance(node, ruml.ScalarNode):

        implicit_tag = self.composer.resolver.resolve(ruml.ScalarNode, node.value, (True, None))
        if implicit_tag in self.yaml_constructors:
            # constructor = CommentedScalar.original_constructors[implicit_tag]
            constructor = self.yaml_constructors[implicit_tag]
        else:
            constructor = self.construct_undefined

        data = constructor(self, node)
        if isinstance(data, types.GeneratorType):
            generator = data
            data = next(generator)  # type: ignore

        scal = CommentedScalar(orig_tag, data)
        yield scal

    elif isinstance(node, ruml.SequenceNode):
        for seq in self.construct_yaml_seq(node):
            seq.yaml_set_tag(orig_tag)
            yield seq
    elif isinstance(node, ruml.MappingNode):
        for map in self.construct_yaml_map(node):
            map.yaml_set_tag(orig_tag)
            yield map
    else:
        for dummy in self.construct_undefined(node):
            yield dummy


def represent_commented_seq(cls, data):
    if data.tag.value is None:
        tag = u'tag:yaml.org,2002:seq'
    else:
        tag = data.tag.value
    return cls.represent_sequence(tag, data)

def get_yaml_serializer():
    """
    Get YAML serialization/deserialization object with proper
    configuration for conversion.
    :return: Confugured instance of ruamel.yaml.YAML.
    """
    yml = ruml.YAML(typ='rt')
    yml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
    yml.width = 120
    yml.representer.add_representer(CommentedScalar, CommentedScalar.to_yaml)
    yml.representer.add_representer(CommentedSeq, represent_commented_seq)
    yml.representer.add_representer(CommentedMap, CommentedMapping.to_yaml)
    yml.constructor.add_multi_constructor("!", construct_any_tag)
    return yml


def get_node_tag(node):
    if hasattr(node, "tag"):
        tag = node.tag.value
        if tag and len(tag) > 1 and tag[0] == '!' and tag[1] != '!':
            return tag
    return ""


def load_yaml(path):
    yml = get_yaml_serializer()
    with open(path, 'r') as stream:
        data = yml.load(stream)
    return data


def write_yaml(data, path):
    yml = get_yaml_serializer()
    with open(path, 'w')as stream:
        yml.dump(data, stream)
```

I was thinking about writing "CommentedMapping" similarly to CommentedScalar but i got stuck here and could not find anything working.

```
@classmethod
def to_yaml(cls, dumper, data):
    ...
    ...
    return ???
```

*Summary*
If someone would push me in right direction I'd be glad. I don't even know if this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All explicitly tagged nodes in your YAML input are mapping nodes, so your `CommentedScalar` is never 
created (with this input).

Since ruamel.yaml in round-trip mode can already load and dump your YAML, you might be better of just walking 
the loaded data and checking for tag attributes.

However it is possible to load those mapping nodes, but not using `yield` in the way you do (and you
only need `yield` for complex nodes (mappings, sequences) not for simple nodes).

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
flow123d_version: 3.1.0
problem: !modulek.Coupling_Sequential
  description: Simple dual porosity test - steady flow, simple transport
  mesh:
    mesh_file: ../00_mesh/square_1x1_40el.msh
  flow_equation: !Flow_Darcy_MH
    nonlinear_solver:
      linear_solver: !Petsc
        a_tol: 1.0e-07
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

@yaml.register_class
class MyMap(ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap):
    def __init__(self, tag):
        ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap.__init__(self)
        self._tag = tag + "@@"  # just to make clear things were changed here

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, data):
        return representer.represent_mapping(data._tag, data)


def construct_any_tag(self, tag_suffix, node):
    if tag_suffix is None:
        orig_tag = None
    else:
        orig_tag = "!" + tag_suffix
    if isinstance(node, ruamel.yaml.nodes.MappingNode):
        data = MyMap(orig_tag)
        yield data
        state = ruamel.yaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.construct_mapping(self, node, deep=True)
        data.update(state)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.constructor.add_multi_constructor("!", construct_any_tag)
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
flow123d_version: 3.1.0
problem: !modulek.Coupling_Sequential@@
  description: Simple dual porosity test - steady flow, simple transport
  mesh:
    mesh_file: ../00_mesh/square_1x1_40el.msh
  flow_equation: !Flow_Darcy_MH@@
    nonlinear_solver:
      linear_solver: !Petsc@@
        a_tol: 1.0e-07
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what i was looking for.