# Using a custom Loader with ruamel.yaml 0.15.0

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

Ruamel.yaml is changing its API: https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#loading

And this seems to remove the support for custom loaders. At least it seems like it. It's unclear how to use custom loaders with the latest API.

For reference my custom loader is:

```py
import io
import os
import ubelt as ub


@ub.memoize
def _custom_ruaml_loader():
    """
    References:
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635900/ruamel-yaml-custom-commentedmapping-for-custom-tags
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528281/how-can-i-include-a-yaml-file-inside-another
    """
    import ruamel.yaml
    Loader = ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader

    def _construct_include_tag(self, node):
        print(f'node={node}')
        if isinstance(node.value, list):
            return [Yaml.coerce(v.value) for v in node.value]
        else:
            external_fpath = ub.Path(node.value)
            if not external_fpath.exists():
                raise IOError(f'Included external yaml file {external_fpath} '
                              'does not exist')
            return Yaml.load(node.value)
    Loader.add_constructor("!include", _construct_include_tag)
    return Loader


Loader = _custom_ruaml_loader()
data = ruamel.yaml.load(file, Loader=Loader, preserve_quotes=True)
```

The warning states that I should do something like:

```py
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml = YAML(typ='unsafe', pure=True)
data = yaml.load(file)
```

But I don't see how I can use a custom `Loader` with this new API.

Has support for custom Loaders been removed, or is there just a new way to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a custom loader, you have the standard `RoundTripLoader` for
which you **extended** the number of tags it can process by adding
a constructor for the tag `!include`. The name `_custom_ruaml_loader` is
misleading, just include `print(type(Loader))` at the end of the
file and you'll see you have an instance of the normal `RoundTripLoader`.

It is unclear where `Yaml` comes from and what is the significance of
you using `ubelt`, so I can't comment on that. Apart from that I'll
assume you have a file `a.yaml` looking like:

```
a: 'xyz'
b: !include b.yaml   # or [b.yaml] but I have no idea what Yaml.coerce does with that
```

and a file `b.yaml`:

```
c: !include c.yaml
d: 42
```

and a file `c.yaml`:

```
e: 2011-10-02
f: enough
```

You can still add constructors for additional tags, and
you can also still add custom constructors.

The constructors are added on a RoundTripConstructor/SafeConstructor/Constructor,
or on a subclass of those ( a Loader is nothing else but a composite of
the various stages of YAML loading, including a Constructor or one of its
subclasses):

```py
import sys
import pathlib
import ruamel.yaml

def _construct_include_tag(constructor, node):
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()  # make a new instance, although you could get the YAML
                               # instance from the constructor argument
    external_fpath = Path(node.value)
    if not external_fpath.exists():
        raise IOError(f'Included external yaml file {external_fpath} '
                        'does not exist')
    res = yaml.load(external_fpath)
    return res

ruamel.yaml.constructor.RoundTripConstructor.add_constructor('!include', _construct_include_tag)
file_in = Path('a.yaml')
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True

data = yaml.load(file_in)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
a: 'xyz'
b:
  c:
    e: 2011-10-02
    f: enough
  d: 42
```

Please note that `ruamel.yaml` can round-trip `a.yaml`, without an added constructor
but that will not do anything special with `!include`, apart from preserving it.

As you can see you don't need a custom constructor. But the above affects all files
loaded with the `RoundTripConstructor`, in this case including the loading
of `b.yaml` as a result of encountering `!include`. And if you don't want that, you can
add your own `Constructor` subclass and add the constructor for tag '!include' to
that, without affecting the `RoundTripConstructor`:

```py
import sys
import pathlib
import ruamel.yaml

class IncludeConstructor(ruamel.yaml.RoundTripConstructor):
    pass

def _construct_include_tag(constructor, node):
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()  # make a new instance, although you could get the YAML
                               # instance from the constructor argument
    external_fpath = Path(node.value)
    if not external_fpath.exists():
        raise IOError(f'Included external yaml file {external_fpath} '
                        'does not exist')
    res = yaml.load(external_fpath)
    return res

IncludeConstructor.add_constructor('!include', _construct_include_tag)

file_in = Path('a.yaml')
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.Constructor = IncludeConstructor
yaml.preserve_quotes = True

data = yaml.load(file_in)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
a: 'xyz'
b:
  c: !include c.yaml
  d: 42
```

because the default RoundTripLoader is not affected the instance of YAML() in
the function `_construct_include_tag` is not affected and `c.yaml` is never
loaded.

This was done with `ruamel.yaml==0.17.32` with Python 3.11.4 on macOS.

Comment: Full context is here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/computer-vision/kwutil/-/blob/main/kwutil/util_yaml.py I didn't do a good job of removing non-necessary parts for the MWE.

Overall, I think your answer tells me what I need to know and corrects my misconceptions. Thanks!